# Display WordPress search results based on the selected Sub-Category

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, search, html

I'm trying to create a search using dropdowns in WordPress.

I've got two dropdowns, 1 - Parent Category and 1 - Sub-category.

The Sub-category will show automatically based on the selected Parent category.

My goal is to have the 2 dropdowns with a submit button and have it act as a search and only displaying the selected sub-category's posts on the results page.

I've got this far using research but I'm completely lost and struggling as you can see.

Below is my functions.php code:

```
// FUNCTIONS.PHP

// Drop-down Ajax call

add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
    if(isset($_POST['main_catid'])) {
        $categories = get_categories('child_of='.$_POST['main_catid'].'&hide_empty=0');
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            $option .= '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">';
            $option .= $cat->cat_name;
            $option .= ' ('.$cat->category_count.')';
            $option .= '</option>';
        }
        echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Search...</option>'.$option;
        die();
    } // end if
}



// Define search for sub-category
function search_filter( $query ) {
    // only modify your custom search query.
    if ( $query->is_search &&  $_post['my_search'] == "c_search") {
        $args = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['main_cat']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['sub_cat']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $args);
    }
    return $query;
}

// The hook needed to search_filter
add_filter( 'the_search_query','search_filter');
```

This is the HTML & JS code used for the form and Ajax call for the sub-categories:

```
<div id="content">
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    <?php
wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=0&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&show_option_none=Main Categories&name=main_cat');
?>
    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" enabled="disabled"></select>
    <input type="hidden" id="my_search" name="my_search" value="c_search" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="search" />
  </div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery('#main_cat').change(function() {
        var $mainCat = jQuery('#main_cat').val();

        // call ajax
        jQuery("#sub_cat").empty();
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'action=my_special_action&main_catid=' + $mainCat,

          success: function(results) {
            //  alert(results);
            jQuery("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery("#sub_cat").append(results);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: your AJAX functions do not have a search query so there is nothing to filter, remember that an AJAX request is a brand new independent request to the server, if you're making that request from a search page that's purely coincidence, there is no shared state between the AJAX request and the original request to load the search page, so stuff like `is_search` will be false

Comment: thanks for this @TomJNowell. I'm still not sure how to go about doing that though, I'm not that familiar with Ajax functions and just used research to get to this point. I've read up on shared states as mentioned but no clue on how to implement this

Comment: there is no shared state, every request loads WordPress from a totally blank slate. Code in your AJAX request cannot modify other requests, and it only knows what it tells you, so unless you send the search term it will have no idea what the search term is. To reiterate, there is no interaction between the code that generated the search page, and the code that runs when you do an AJAX request. The only things they share, are the database, cookies, and the things you pass it when you make your AJAX request. When you make your AJAX request the original request that created the page is gone

Comment: so right now, your AJAX request is returning the category HTML, but you need to request the search results, display the results, and return them to the user, then take that HTML string and insert it into the page. At this point it would be easier to just do it without AJAX ( and a little bit faster ), aka watch the category inputs and refresh the page with parameters in the URL that come from the dropdowns. You can do this without any javascript using a form if your dropdowns have the right `name` values and it's a standard WP archivesearch page rather than a page template.

Comment: there's even a legacy WP function to display a dropdown that leads to an archive page, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/ javascript and AJAX are unnecessary

Comment: and if you want 2 dropdowns with the second changing depending on the first, AJAX isn't necessary for that either, have 1 dropdown then have a dropdown for every option and hide the ones you don't want to be visible based on the option chosen. Also, your AJAX handler only does something if `main_catid` is set, but what if it isn't set? Now it's not going to do anything and it doesn't die/exit either so ???? you need to handle that situation